# Como manipular propiedades de controles creados dinamicamente

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Estoy empezando a trabajar con botones creados dinámicamente, el código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
    private void crearbotones()
            {
                int x = 5, y = 5;
                for (int i = 1; i < cantgenerar + 1; i++)
                {
                    Button btn1 = new Button();
                    btn1.Height = 50;
                    btn1.Width = 50;
                    btn1.Location = new Point(x, y); //Posicion
                    y = y + 60;
                    //Acomodado de botones
                    if (y > 420) //Si hay 7 botones en la misma linea aumentamos la posicion X para crear otra linea al lado y no salirnos de la pantalla
                    {
                        y = 10;
                        x = x + 60;
                    }
                    btn1.Name = "c" + i.ToString();
                    btn1.Text = "Btn " + i.ToString();
                    Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
                    //Agregar handler al boton para que haga algo
                    btn1.Click += new EventHandler(Clicks);
                    //Agregar el boton al Form
                    Controls.Add(btn1);
                }
            }

private void Clicks(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (((Button)sender).Name == "c3")
            {
                //ocultar este botón
            }
        }
```

Quisiera saber como cambiar alguna propiedad a algún botón, digamos que quiero ocultar en ese caso el botón que se llama c3 al presionarlo, o en algún dado caso cambiar su Texto mas adelante, o cambiar el fondo o algunas otras propiedades. Quisiera saber como hacer para lograr alguna de estas acciones.
Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

podrias intentarlo asi

```c#
private void Clicks(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   var button = sender as Button;
   if (button!= null && button.Name == "c3")
      button.Hide(); 
}
```

Comment: Gracias, esto funciona con el mismo botón que se presionó y me es útil, ahora, como podría cambiar la propiedad de otro botón diferente al que se presiona, digamos, al presionar el c3, que oculte el c1 por ejemplo

Comment: Listo, ya resolvi la duda anterior, lo resolvi con el siguiente código: private void Clicks(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FormJuego frmjuego = new FormJuego();
            if (((Button)sender).Name == "c3")
            {
                Button btn1 = this.Controls.Find("c1", false).First() as Button;
                if(btn1 != null)
                {
                    btn1.Visible = false;
                }
            }
        }  Gracias por la ayuda :)

Answer (score 1):

Para poder gestionar los botones que creas dinámicamente te recomiendo crear un:

```
List<Button> _DButtons = new List<Button>();
```

Como atributo de clase; al momento de crear los botones (en el método `crearbotones()`), los agregas a la lista justo antes de agregarlos a la colección `Controls` del `Form`:

```
_DButtons.Add(btn1)
```

Entonces, al momento del evento `Click`  obtienes el objeto actual y lo válidas:

```
var button = sender as Button;
if (button != null && button.Name == "C3")
{
    var other = (from b in _DButtons where b.Name == "C1" select b).SingleOrDefault();
    if (other != null)
        other.Hide();
}
```

> Nota: Para la consulta en la Lista se necesita la referencia
>   `System.Linq`

Así puedes darle el funcionamiento dinámico como lo necesites.